# I'm unable to find the correct formula to count blank cells and fill in a column in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm trying to fill with "Yes/No" in the "Final Sheet" sheet based on the check-in and check-out data in the "Attendance EST II" sheet, but I'm not finding the right formula.
[This is the Excel file below](https://github.com/AbbasSH99/Files/blob/main/EXCEL%20TASK%20%2B%20INSTRUCTIONS%20(DATA%20ANALYST).xlsx)

I tried writing the formula below but it did not work. All I'm getting is (We found a problem with this formula).

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP([@email], TblAttendEST2[Email]:TblAttendEST2[Physics-Out], 1,FALSE) = A2, IF(COUNTBLANK(VLOOKUP([@email], TblAttendEST2[Email]:TblAttendEST2[Physics-Out], {2,3,4,5,6,7}, FALSE)) = 6, "No", "Yes") "No"), "No")
```

Comment: Your file is damaged. You saved it in wrong format.

Comment: @DamirTenishev can you please explain further.

Comment: Save your file in Excel format (not only the extension, but the format itself) and re-upload it. Now you have damaged file under your link. Just download it and try to open with Excel.

Comment: You don't state your logic for indicating attendance, so I can only critique your formula.

Answer (score 0):

There are two significant problems with your formula:

- You are missing the comma prior to the penultimate "No"
- The argument for `COUNTBLANK` must be a `Range` and your argument will be an array or an error.

But, if I understand your logic, it is that

- if there are two or more entries in the matching row, then "Yes" else "No"
- You do not check if those entries both refer to the same course

That being the case, I believe you could simplify your formula to:

```
=IF(COUNT(VLOOKUP([@email], TblAttendEST2[Email]:TblAttendEST2[Physics-Out], {2,3,4,5,6,7}, FALSE))>1,"Yes","No")
```

If you want a `Yes` if there is one or more times filled in, then merely remove the `>1` from the above formula:

```
=IF(COUNT(VLOOKUP([@email], TblAttendEST2[Email]:TblAttendEST2[Physics-Out], {2,3,4,5,6,7}, FALSE)),"Yes","No")
```